# CoreData TextField - unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data, null

I'm doing application with CoreData and textfields in tableview. In storyboard I have one textfield. textfield will multiply five times with different content in application. In navigation bar I have button that will save your written data. But when I press save button, application crash with error

[image]

IBOutlet is in the TableViewCell.swift. Code from image:

```
    @IBAction public func saveTapped(){

        if activeTextField.text.isEmpty {
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Nevyplnené údaje"
            alert.message = "Musíš vyplniť všetky údaje o knihe."
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()


        }
        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let obsah: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("List", inManagedObjectContext: obsah)
        var pridat = Model(entity: entity! , insertIntoManagedObjectContext: obsah)

        pridat.kniha = activeTextField.text
        pridat.autor = activeTextField.text
        pridat.rok = activeTextField.text
        pridat.vydavatelstvo = activeTextField.text
        pridat.strany = activeTextField.text

        obsah.
}
```

Here's full code:

http://pastebin.com/6LHqJW0w

Here's TableViewCell code:

http://pastebin.com/RAYTUcp6

I also tried

```
    let mfv = TableViewCell()

        if mfv.textField.text.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Nevyplnené údaje"
        alert.message = "Musíš vyplniť všetky údaje o knihe."
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
```

Comment: If you want help from SO users please! take the time to type out your code. Images are hard to read and unnecessary. Also if somebody does wish to test something regarding your question before posting a answer they can’t copy your code.

Comment: sorry man :X edited:)

Comment: Debug the value of `var activeTextField: UITextField!` I suspect your `UITextField is nil` (since the text property can’t be nil neither can the `.isEmpty`)

Comment: Check if the IBOutlet for the activeTextField is connected

Comment: thats the point IBOutlet is in the tableviewcell.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set the value of `activeTextField` when the `UITextField` delegate methods are triggered.  However, I can't see where you are setting your view controller to be the `delegate` for those textfields.  I think you will need to add something to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (or may be in the cell's `configure` method) to set the textField's `delegate`.

**EDIT**

I would amend your `configure` method to set the textField's delegate:

```
public func configure(placeholder: String, delegate : UITextFieldDelegate) {
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
        textField.accessibilityLabel = placeholder
        textField.delegate = delegate

    }
```

and amend the view controller likewise (wherever you call `configure`):

```
    cell!.configure("...", delegate:self)
```

**END EDIT**

I would also make `activeTextField` fully optional (not implicitly unwrapped), since it is entirely possible that it will be nil (if, for example, save is tapped before any textField has been edited).  You should then use `if let` to unwrap the optional in the `saveTapped` method.

Comment: how to make activetextfield fully optional?

Comment: Declare it with ? rather than !, like this `var activeTextField: UITextField?`.  Then when you want to use it, use `if let textField = activeTextField {...` to unwrap it.

Comment: Now when i press save button it does nothing

Comment: Do the delegate methods (particularly textField:didBeginEditing:) get called?

Comment: Your view controller has a public function entitled `textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)` .  That should be called when you edit the text in the textfield in your cells.  To check, add a line `println("textFieldDidBeginEditing was called")` to log whether the function gets called.

Comment: OK.  Have you made any changes to set the textField delegate?  I'll update my answer to explain it some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76828/discussion-between-patffo-and-pbasdf).

Comment: I'm happy to chat, but I'm busy right now.  Maybe in an hour?

Comment: Okey mail me when you can patffo@icloud.com